# Как реализовать переключение цветовых схем на сайте с помощью jquery так, чтобы после перезагрузки страницы цветовая схема не слетала...?

Tags: jquery, css, link

Как реализовать переключение цветовых схем на сайте  с помощью jquery так, чтобы после перезагрузки страницы цветовая схема не слетала...?

Comment: Сохранять стиль в куках, сессии, БД.

Comment: В `localStorage` ещё можно, но лучший вариант в БД, так как даже если пользователь перейдет на другой браузер информация сохраниться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Один из вариантов это использование [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

Минус этого варианта это то что при использовании другого компьютера, другого браузера эта информация будет сброшена.

Самый лучший вариант это сохранять текущие настройки в базу данных.